# Jest/Enzyme with create-react-app Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app, enzyme

I'm having an issue when trying to run tests on components inside a CRA app. I'm new to Jest/Enzyme and have run very similar tests in one CRA app which I created specifically to learn unit testing, but when I try to integrate it into an existing project, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/dave/Teacher_App/client_teacher/App.test.js: Unexpected token (12:20)

  10 | 
  11 |   beforeEach(() => {
> 12 |     wrapper = mount(<App />)
     |                     ^
  13 |     console.log(wrapper.debug()) 
  14 |   })
  15 |
```

I have tried the suggestions provided in the terminal and have read a bunch of answers to other posts on here with the same issue, but nothing seems to be working!

Here are the contents of my ./setupTests.js

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

and ./App.test.js

```
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';

import { mount } from 'enzyme';


describe('counter testing', () => {

  let wrapper ;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
  })

  test('renders the title of the dash', () => {
    
    expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toContain("Dashboard")

  });

})
```

and also my package.json (it's a pretty big app!)

```
{
  "name": "app-schools",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.3.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.3-4",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.14",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@use-hooks/image-size": "^1.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.2.5",
    "crossfilter2": "^1.4.7",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "dc": "^3.2.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.3",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "glamor": "^2.20.40",
    "google-classroom-share": "^0.5.4",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-country-region-selector": "^3.0.2",
    "react-countup": "^4.3.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.3",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "^0.7.4",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-flip-page": "^1.6.4",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-picker": "^0.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-load-script": "0.0.6",
    "react-masonry-css": "^1.0.14",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-player": "^2.7.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-script-tag": "^1.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-share": "^4.2.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^5.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "typography": "^0.16.19",
    "typography-theme-funston": "^0.16.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the contents of the App.jsx component, stripped down whilst trying to debug:

```
import React from 'react';


const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

I assume I am missing some setting somewhere. This is a non-ejected CRA app, so I cannot modify the babel config file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post also the code of App component? thanks

Comment: Hi @axel, I have added that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your file extension seems to be incorrect which is why it's having issues acknolweding that there's `jsx` in your file. Change the file extension for `App.test.js` to `App.test.jsx`.

I would also recommend ditching Enzyme for React Testing Library since you are using DOM testing library. Enzyme is going into a state where newer versions of React will require third party adaptors which will be awkward when you want to eventually go above version 16.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the swift response.

Unfortunately changing the extension had no effect :( 

Thanks for the advice regarding the React Testing Library, perhaps I'll give that a go.

Comment: @DaveClydesdale do you have the code available? :) Can we see your babel file

Comment: Hey @Win , as this is a non-ejected CRA app, I do not have access to the babel config. Just package.json

Comment: @DaveClydesdale hmm, it's a little difficult to resolve because I want to check if the babel transform jsx plugin is installed, do you have discord where I might be able to assist?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not! :( I see it is a huge pain to debug and I really appreciate the effort.

Comment: @DaveClydesdale What version of CRA did you use? I would try importing all of your project code into a fresh install and use react testing library as it ships with CRA by default now :) Or eject the CRA build by copying the folder and leaving the original alone and show me the babelrc file

Comment: Awesome, those are some really great suggestions. I am going to give both a try! I will report back.  
I'm not 100% sure which version of CRA I'm working with, the project uses React 16.13.1